# Server-side rendering (SSR) with Angular Universal issues with swarm-js

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

On running the command for server-side rendering: `ng run <project-name>:server:production`

Getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/swarm-js/node_modules/got/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './package' in 'Project-path\node_modules\swarm-js\node_modules\got'

ERROR in ./node_modules/swarm-js/node_modules/got/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'electron' in 'Project-path\node_modules\swarm-js\node_modules\got'
```

I'm using Angular 10 and Windows system.

Comment: Introspecting further I reached to below two conclusions:

One of the libraries is trying to require package.json file using below command
const pkg = require('./package');
We are using a library that uses a conditional require statement which tries to require electron if the condition fulfills.
In the first case, SSR build is unable to require package.json if the extension is not mentioned.
In the second case, SSR build is trying to resolve the conditional require statements as well.

Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Have you resolve this issue ?

Comment: Yes, the newer version of swarm-js resolves the issue.

Comment: Which version solved the issue?